# Showing recently viewed prodcuts only if there are any

Tags: magento-1.9, template, product-list

I added "Recently viewed products" to the bottom of the product view page by adding this code in to local.xml file:

```
<!-- Showing Recently Viewed Products on Product View Page -->
<catalog_product_view translate="label">    
    <reference name="content">         
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />     
    </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

It works great, however the container for the recently viewed product is always showing even if there are no recently viewed products.

How can I add a condition to the above code in local.xml so that the "Recently viewed product" should show only if any recentley viewed product exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default template `reports/product_viewed.phtml` already does this:

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    ....
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If there are no recently viewd products, `$this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()` returns null and nothing is displayed.

Probably your theme has its own product_viewed.phtml template, please make sure, it contains this condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Homtom,please change

Check reference name may be `product.info` instead  of `content` if want to  show at `view.phtml`

At `catalog/product/view.phtml` you need to call this by callling html

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed');?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But if I change the code as you have suggested, then "Recently viewed products" dosent show at all!! Any idea why?